# Capturing all <a> click events

Tags: javascript, events, capture

I am thinking of to add a javascript function to capture all the `<a>` click events inside a html page.

So I am adding a global function that governs all the `<a>` click events, but not adding onclick to each  (neither using `.onclick=` nor `attachEvent(onclick...)` nor inline `onclick=`). I will leave each `<a>` as simple as `<a href="someurl">` within the html without touching them.

I tried `window.onclick = function (e) {...}`
but that just captures all the clicks
How do I specify only the clicks on `<a>` and to extract the links inside `<a>` that is being clicked?

**Restriction**: I don't want to use any exra libraries like jQuery, just vanilla javascript.

Comment: Sorry I edited. It was missing all the html tags...

Comment: "Restriction: I don't want to use any exra libraries like jQuery, just vanilla javascript." - I love you officially.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/):

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  const origin = e.target.closest(`a`);
  
  if (origin) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(`You clicked ${origin.href}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#l1">some link</a>
  <div><a href="#l2"><div><i>some other (nested) link</i></div></a></div>
</div>
```

[**edit 2020/08/20**] Modernized

Answer (score 29):

You can handle all click using window.onclick and then filter using event.target

Example as you asked:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.target);};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes please. I will select you if you have code example how to filter and extract the href

Comment: Thanks! Well it end up it is a combination of your e.target and xdazz's e.target.localName. But since you beat xdazz to it a few minutes, I will pick you

Comment: ! this will handle and textfield clicks

Comment: This will capture more than just <a> clicks. @Kooilnc 's approach limits this the clicks to link presses.

Comment: @William as I said, you will have to filter on `event.target`.

Comment: @ArturUdod OP asks; 'How do I specify only the clicks on <a>', the code presented doesn't do that, and folks may not know how to filter on event.target, so highlighting Kooilnc's answer helps illustrate this.

Answer (score 9):

```
​window.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.localName == 'a') {
        console.log('a tag clicked!');
    }
}​
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/B72JJ/)***

Comment: Thanks! e.target.localName works great! I can use this with e.target to get the link!

Comment: [This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/localName)

Answer (score 5):

your idea to delegate the event to the window and then check if the "event.target" is a link, is one way to go (better would be document.body). The trouble here is that it won't work if you click on a child node of your element. Think:

```
<a href="#"><b>I am bold</b></a>
```

the `target` would be the `<b>` element, not the link. **This means checking for `e.target` won't work**. So, you would have to crawl up all the dom tree to check if the clicked element is a descendant of a `<a>` element.

Another method that requires less computation on every click, but costs more to initialize would be to get all `<a>` tags and attach your event in a loop:

```
var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')
);

var count = links.length;
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //your code here
    });
}
```

(PS: why do I convert the HTMLCollection to array? [here's the answer.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHtdZgou0qU&feature=player_detailpage#t=1561s))

Comment: Very informative! It shows your detailed knowledge on this matter! But this is more than I can chew. I checked the video, thats really advance for me. But surely your knowledge would be useful for someone else!

Answer (score 5):

You need to take into account that a link can be nested with other elements and want to traverse the tree back to the 'a' element. This works for me:

```js
window.onclick = function(e) {
  var node = e.target;
  while (node != undefined && node.localName != 'a') {
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  if (node != undefined) {
    console.log(node.href);
    /* Your link handler here */
    return false;  // stop handling the click
  } else {
    return true;  // handle other clicks
  }
}
```

See e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/hnmdijkema/nn5akf3b/6/

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery and

```
$('a').click(function(event) { *your code here* });
```

In this function you can extract href value in this way:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Comment: sorry no, no extra library, just IE9 or Firefox 15

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using this:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
forEach.call(links, function (link) {
    link.onclick = function () {
        console.log('Clicked');
    }

});
```

It works, I just tested!

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CR7Sz/

Somewhere in comments you mentioned you want to get the 'href' value you can do that with this:

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
forEach.call(links, function (link) {
    link.onclick = function () {
        console.log(link.href); //use link.href for the value
    }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CR7Sz/1/

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is looking for the typed version (TypeScript, using Kooilnc's answer), here it is:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
    if(!e.target) { return; }
    if(!(e.target instanceof Element)) { return; }
    
    const origin = e.target.closest("a");
    if(!origin || !origin.href) { return; }
    
    console.log(`You clicked ${origin.href}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some accepted answers dont work with nested elements like: 

`<a href="..."><font><u>link</u></font></a>`

There is a basic solution for most cases:
```

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i in links)
{
    links[i].onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        // ... do what you need here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this simple code will work with jquery.

```
 $("a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Without JQuery:

```
window.onclick = function(e) { 
if(e.target.localName=='a')
    alert(e.target);
};
```

The above will produce the same result.

Comment: The author of the question says in the comments that he don't want to use any libraries, just vanilla javascript. I will add those comments to the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Hi Morten, As you asked I edited the code for plain javascript. :)

Answer (score -3):

Very simple :

```
document.getElementById("YOUR_ID").onclick = function (e) {...}
```

The selector is what you want to select so lets say you have button called

```
<a href="#" id="button1">Button1</a>
```

The code to capure this is:

```
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function (e) { alert('button1 clicked'); }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I dont want to manually add onclick to every single ID. I want a global function that captures all already then I do filtering inside