# this.form.submit() not working

Tags: html, form-submit

```
    <form name="formUnbook" method="post" action='<%=response.encodeURL("dist-sales-order-edit.do")%>'>
                        <input type="hidden" name="formName"  value=<%=formName%>>
                        <input type="hidden" name="docTableItem" value="<%=docTableItem%>"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="docKeyItem" value="<%=docKeyItem%>"> 
                        <%eventCalendarLinkName  = "UnBook";%>
<a class="smalllink4" href="#" onClick="fnUnbook();"><%=eventCalendarLinkName%></a>
</form>
......................................................................................
<script language="JavaScript">
        function fnUnbook(){
            answer = confirm('<%=bundle.getString("label_areYouSure")%>');
            if(answer)
            {
                this.form.submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This.form.submit(); doesn't submit the form. Any suggestion? I also tried document.form.submit(); but doesn't worked. Where is the problem?

Comment: Does the confirm dialog appear?

Comment: you get the form document.getElementsByName('formUnbook').submith

Comment: @VostanAzatyan `getElementsByName` returns a collection...

Comment: when in doubt, `console.log(this)`, it will always help you debug, I think `this` is  the `<a>` in this case, and that `<a>` is inside the form, not the other way, so it should be something like `this.parentNode.submit()` instead I think. Also Being an A you have to capture the event and use event.preventDefault() or similar.

Comment: yes confirm dialog appears

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo that only if you have 2 or more elements by same name ...

Comment: @VostanAzatyan always https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName - collection with 1 element only is still a collection.

Comment: In your case, `this` is the `window` object, I've just tested, that's why `window.form.submit()` don't work, you should have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551920/capturing-all-the-a-click-event

Answer (score 3):

change `this.form.submit();` to `document.getElementsByName("formUnbook")[0].submit();`

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code like that (add `id` to the form):

```
<form name="formUnbook" id="formUnbook" method="post" action='<%=response.encodeURL("dist-sales-order-edit.do")%>'>
<!-- other stuff here -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function fnUnbook() {
  if( confirm('<%=bundle.getString("label_areYouSure")%>') ) {
    return document.getElementById('formUnbook').submit();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null dist-sales-order-edit.do:2264
fnUnbook dist-sales-order-edit.do:2264
onclick

Comment: Add attribute `id` to the form, as is written in my answer with value `formUnbook`.

Answer (score 0):

the context this is lost during calling your function, use this code :

```
    <form name="formUnbook" id="formUnbook" method="post" action='<%=response.encodeURL("dist-sales-order-edit.do")%>'>
...
    <script language="JavaScript">
           function fnUnbook(elmt){
               answer = confirm('<%=bundle.getString("label_areYouSure")%>');
               if(answer)
               {
                   document.formUnbook.submit();
               }
           }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

give id of your form

```
<form id="newForm" name="formUnbook" method="post" action='<%=response.encodeURL("dist-sales-order-edit.do")%>'>
....
....
</form>
```

and use getElement method

```
function fnUnbook(){
            answer = confirm('<%=bundle.getString("label_areYouSure")%>');
            if(answer)
            {
                document.getElementById("newForm").submit();
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: awww you were faster than me :b

Comment: Syntax error, you have misspell the `documet`, should be `document`

Answer (score 0):

add form id to your form

```
     <form id="form"......
```

and change from **this.form.submit** to

```
     document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

Hope it works

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null dist-sales-order-edit.do:2264
fnUnbook dist-sales-order-edit.do:2264
onclick

Comment: @Rehaan , try Man Programmer code. I did not use the right capital, it sould be document.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Use global `document` collection of forms:

```
for (var i=0; i<document.forms.length; i++){
    var currentForm = document.forms[0];
    if (currentForm.name == 'formUnbook'){
        currentForm.submit();
        break;
    }
}
```