# Chrome Extension: Detect click outside of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In short, I am trying to make the extension itself reload when anything is clicked in the browser portion of the screen.  I found, [Capturing all the <a> click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551920/capturing-all-the-a-click-event), which gave me 
window.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.target);};

but this only throws an alert if something is clicked inside the extension.  Is there a way to detect a click outside of the extension itself and make that reload the extension?

Comment: You would need to use content script on all pages to detect click and send message to background script to reload

Comment: I believe you are correct, but I am asking how I would do that?

Comment: @kundrata approach is better and should work

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I will say you can only get clicks from individual tabs opened. So you'll miss the URL bar and any other portion of the browser that's outside the tab area.

Here's how you can capture clicks on all tabs. Note: Place code in your background page.

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[i].id, {code:"window.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.target);};"},
                function(){} );
    }
});
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab)  { 
   chrome.tabs.executeScript( tab.id, {code:"window.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.target);};"},
   function(){} );
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab)  { 
   chrome.tabs.executeScript( tab.id, {code:"window.onclick = function(e) { alert(e.target);};"},
   function(){} );
});
```

To notify your extension that a click occured on one of your tabs, use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`-- you can intercept this message in your background page by adding `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`. When you received the message, you can reload the extension using `chrome.runtime.reload();`

So instead, of calling `alert()` when a click happens, use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, and when your background page gets the message, `chrome.runtime.reload` should do the job of reloading the extension.

Final code, all placed in your background page, would look like so:

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[i].id, {code:"window.onclick = function(e) { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msgID: "click_event"});};"},
                function(){} );
    }
});
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab)  { 
   chrome.tabs.executeScript( tab.id, {code:"window.onclick = function(e) { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msgID: "click_event"});};"},
   function(){} );
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab)  { 
   chrome.tabs.executeScript( tab.id, {code:"window.onclick = function(e) { chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msgID: "click_event"});};"},
   function(){} );
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, resp){

    if(req.msgID.indexOf("click_event") > -1)
    {   
       chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is amazing!  Thank you!