# Is there any way to make the onClick global or DRY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("input").on("keypress",function(e){
    if(e.which===13){
        $("ul").last().append("<li>"+$(this).val()+"</li>");
    }
    $("li").on("click",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("striked");
    });

    $("li").on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).css("color","green");
    });
});
$("li").on("click",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("striked");
});
$("li").on("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).css("color","green");
});
$("#slide").on("click",function(){
    $("input").slideToggle();
});
```

Here, I have used the `onClick` event on`<li>` to apply the striked class two times just to make it work for both **dynamic and non-dynamic elements** on the page. But the **code is replicated** and seems long. Is there any way to shorten so that **I can write it once and it gets activated for both types of elements**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation instead, on the `ul`, so you only have to set up listeners *once*, rather than setting up multiple listeners for every element on load *and* on each `.append`. Also, save the `ul` and the `input` jQuery-wrapped elements in a variable *once* rather than selecting them and wrapping them with jQuery each time they're used:

```
const $ul = $("ul");
const $input = $("input");
$input.on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    $ul.last().append("<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>");
  }
});

$ul.on("click", 'li', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("striked");
});
$ul.on("mouseenter", 'li', function() {
  $(this).css("color", "green");
});
$("#slide").on("click", function() {
  $input.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Yep, and in generally that's right way to handle events on similar elements in a container, not assigning a separate handler for each one. many developers are not aware of this possibility. Great answer!

Comment: Great answer. One question though. Is the parent element necessary? Like here you used ul as the parent for li. What if I have no parent element?

Comment: Since the question title talks about DRY, you could chain the `.on` or even attach both click and mousenter has a single call using the plain object notation (`$ul.on({click:onliclick, mousenter:onlimouseenter}, 'li')`) @AjayKudva unless you are targeting :root (the documentElement), you always have a parent

Comment: @AjayKudva If you're `append`ing (whether with jQuery or vanilla JS), then you *do* surely have some parent container you're appending the elements to, right? If there's no parent to append to, nothing can be appended..? (or, what were you thinking of?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are right. Didn't think of that. Sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: the only thing I can add is that you can daisy chain your handlers i.e. `$ul.on("click", 'li', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("striked");
}).on("mouseenter", 'li', function() {
  $(this).css("color", "green");
});`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, may I ask you to have a look at a jQuery related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468968/jquery-click-at-a-co-ordinate-on-an-image-and-draw-a-circle-there ?

Answer (score 0):

A rather generic approach would be to capture the click event and check if it is from ul

```
document.body.onclick = function(e){
  e = e || event;
  var from = findParent('ul',e.target || e.srcElement);
  if (from){
     /* it's a link, actions here */
  }
}
//find first parent with tagName [tagname]
function findParent(tagname,el){
  while (el){
    if ((el.nodeName || el.tagName).toLowerCase()===tagname.toLowerCase()){
      return el;
    }
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return null;
}
```

now you can change the tagName passed to the `findParent` function and do accordingly

[Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551920/capturing-all-the-a-click-event)

Answer (score -2):

You can try using the jquery all selector `$('*')`. For more information on this see 
https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/.

Or you can add a specific class to every element you want to have an onClick action.